# How to show more then 10 tiles in Cortana list

Tags: uwp, cortana

How to show more then 10 tiles in VoiceCommandContentTile?
I'm thinking if I can create a tile and LaunchArgument can open second page of list like 11-20 if I have total of 20 tiles.
Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            if (selectedRes.SelectedItem.AppLaunchArgument == "more")
            {

                await CortanaList();                    
            }
```

Found out is not that hard. 
 1. load only 4 or 9 tiles
 2. List item be more tiles button
 3. catch the AppLaunchArgument and return method again